# Update panel inside modal popup

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, updatepanel

I have a asp.net checkboxlist inside update panel in a modal popup and I have to refresh it on click of a button which is outside the modal popup. 
I am getting following Error:
A control with ID 'btnAddFav' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel6'.
please help me with this..
I cant resolve the issue.

Comment: include some code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the code used.

You may cross check if the HTML of the model window is well formatted(all proper tags closed/contained).

Comment: I found the solution here.

http://weblogs.asp.net/pauljuenger/archive/2008/10/10/triggering-an-update-panel-from-a-control-in-a-different-contentplaceholder.aspx

I was getting that error because Update Panel(UpdatePanel6) and the triggering control(btnAddFav) were in a different ContentPlaceHolders.

Thanks